# How can I check for SSL vulnerabilities on my web server?

Tags: security, ssl, pci-dss

Is there an easy way or online tool for checking a site's SSL vulnerability issues?

From the [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) standards I see that a site has to force SSLv3 or TLSv1 protocols and high security encryption algorithms. And I need to check if my site is compliant with those PCI DSS standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download [Nessus](http://www.nessus.org/)  which is free and scans for a number of known SSL vulnerabilities to see the list of SSL related scans [go to this link](http://www.nessus.org/plugins/index.php) on the left side click search then enter SSL into the search box, there are over 200 SSL security checks. (note: most will not apply to your situation necessarily)

Answer (score 2):

These three sites are all currently (April 2011) offering free scans...

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/index.html

http://www.serversniff.net/content.php?do=ssl

http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html